# Kendo DatePicker in UK with US format

Tags: c#, datepicker, kendo-asp.net-mvc

We are in the UK but have a US client. We want the date of a Kendo DatePicker to display in US format `MM-dd-yyy` but, testing here, it won't accept any selection of a date value, stating that it must be a valid date.

I have applied `.Format("MM-dd-yyyy")` to display the value, which works. I have attempted a couple of things to get it to accept a date selection, as you can see here:

```
@(Html
        .Kendo()
        .DatePickerFor(model => model.Date)
        .Name("Date")
        //.Format("MM-dd-yyyy")
        //.ParseFormats(new[] { "dd/MM/yyyy", "dd-MM-yyyy", "MM-dd-yyyy" })
        .Culture("en-US")
        .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:150px" })
)
```

How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally got this to work.

In JavaScript we can specify

```
kendo.culture("en-US");
```

but the key piece of code I used to get it to work was:

```
function OnSave(e) {
    e.model.Date = (e.model.Date).toUTCString();
}
```

Even though `e.model.Date` was already a valid (UK) date, `toUTCString` enables an automatic conversion that Kendo/C# can convert to an acceptable date in the model.